# Does seekg() function work on the standard input or just in files

Tags: c++, file, seek

does the cin.seekg(0,std::ios::beg) work on standard input? or is there even such a function where i can re-access the beginning of the input after already reading it ? thank you in advance

Comment: It works on standard input if standard input is a file.

Comment: @melpomene is it possible to put the standard input (which is not a file) in a file so I can access it?